# mysql full text search right index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, mariadb, full-text-indexing

lets say I have table `posts` with this columns:
`top_totle,title,sub_title,text`

I need to have full text search on all this column and order by relevance where top_title need to be more important then title etc.

so i have 2 question which are the same, what is the best way of making an index for this and how to format the query to best support this index?

index options:
I can create combined full text index on all of this column or create separate index for each of this column

which is the prefered way?
option 1:

```
SELECT
  title,
  MATCH (top_title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as toptitle_score,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as title_score,
  MATCH (sub_text) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as sub_text_score,
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE
  MATCH (top_title,title , sub_text ) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  and `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `published_at` IS NOT NULL
Order by toptitle_score desc, 
Order by title_score desc , 
Order by subtext_score desc
```

option 2:

```
SELECT
  title,
  MATCH (top_title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as toptitle_score,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as title_score,
  MATCH (sub_text) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as sub_text_score,
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE
  (MATCH (top_title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  or MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  or MATCH (sub_text) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
  and `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `published_at` IS NOT NULL
Order by toptitle_score desc, 
Order by title_score desc , 
Order by subtext_score desc
```

option 3:

```
is there some smarter way?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is good.  It needs 4 FT indexes (one per column, plus one with all 3 columns).  Don't repeat `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY toptitle_score DESC , 
         title_score    DESC , 
         subtext_score  DESC
```

Option 2 is not a viable contender.  It needs only 3 indexes (not much savings) but is a lot slower due to `OR`.

Option 3...  (Option 1, as fixed, plus...)

The `ORDER BY` you are using is probably "wrong" for what you want.  For example, it will shove to the end of the list any rows without `text` in `toptitle`.  Perhaps you want some "weighted" version:

```
ORDER BY
   9 * top_title_score  +
   3 * title_score      +
   1 * sub_text_score  DESC
```

(The 9,3,1 are rather arbitrary.  It says that if 'text' shows up more than 3 times in `title`, that is more important than showing up once in `top_title` -- or something like that.)